# Relationship between "uniqueness of the subgroup and normal"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let the group, $G$

There is a unique subgroup $H (\leq G) s.t. \vert H \vert =n$  then, $H \lhd G$

---

I believe that the above statement is true. Let me allow telling my proof idea to you.

If we take the $\phi_g : G \to G $ by $H \to gHg^{-1},  \forall g \in G$ ($\phi_g$ is Inner automorphism)

Then $\phi(H) \leq G$ and $\vert  \phi(H) \vert = n$. By the way, there is a unique subgroup whose order is $n$.  This means $\phi(H) = H$.

Hence $gHg^{-1} = H$(I.e. $H \lhd G$)

I have a little confidence my proof and statement is true. But, Can't totally ensure myself all the things right. Are my statement and proof right?

Thanks.

Comment: This is correct. Well done. $H$ is even *characteristic*, meaning fixed by *any* automorphism of $G$.

Comment: Your proof is 'correct' but the definition for the conjugation automorphism should be $\phi_g:G\to G$ where $x\mapsto g^{-1}xg$.

Comment: Huh, @Sebastian Cor, why would that be? The author only shows that conjugation leads to another subgroup of the same order.

Comment: I dont think defined that way it defines a morphism since the product of two subgroups need not be a subgroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By contrapositive, suppose $H$ is not normal in $G$; then, $\exists a\in G \mid Ha \ne aH$; but then $aHa^{-1}$ is a subgroup of order $n^{(*)}$ distinct from $H$, contradiction. So, your statement is true.

$^{(*)}$Because the map $H \to aHa^{-1}$, defined by $h \mapsto aha^{-1}$, is bijective.